# Access ionic2 API lockSwipes() method

Tags: ionic2

Ionic2 docs list for a specific component some API methods.

For the slider component there is meant to be a lockSwipes() method.

While some of the methods exist, when I call lockSwipes() my typescript compiler tells me it doesn't exist!

I am on the latest version of ionic2 as of 2017 Feb.

Someone said something about modifying the typescript definitions but I don't know if this is something I should/could do myself.

Below is my packages.json

```
    {
  "name": "myApp",
  "author": "Company!",
  "homepage": "http://www.website.com",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^1.1.6",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.45",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "WCGoalsIonic: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: can you share your package.json file?

Comment: added file to my question. thanks